# Can you crack this mod of the Caesar cipher?

Tags: cipher

I want to know how secure/insecure my implementation of the Caesar cipher is...

Ciphertext to decrypt:

```
39 83 82 75 86 69 88 89 80 69 88 77 83 82 87 4 83 82 4 72 73 71 86 93 84 88 77 82 75 4 88 76 77 87 4 81 73 87 87 69 75 73 4 5 4 18 18 18 4 45 4 72 77 72 4 82 83 88 4 88 76 77 82 79 4 77 88 4 91 83 89 80 72 4 70 73 4 90 73 86 93 4 87 73 71 89 86 73 4 69 82 93 91 69 93 87 4 31 13 -18 0 -111
```

**Hints/Clues:**

[C Source](https://github.com/a-p-jo/C5/blob/master/C5.c) [Of program used for encryption/decryption - For those who know basic C]

Algorithm/Steps:

- **Encryption**:

1. Numeric Pin is taken. Pin should have 1 to 6 digits.
2. Key is made from Pin. Key = (sum of digits in PIN - (sum/6))
3. A Message is taken from the user, stored into a char array `msg[]`
4. Each character x in `msg[]` is changed as: `int d  = (x - key)`. Here, the ASCII value of char x is operated on.
5. Each int is stored in an int array `en[]`. Then, all these ints are printed, with a space separating these, and the last number is always -111

- **Decryption**:

1. Pin is taken and key is generated from it.
2. Ciphertext is taken from user. Whitespace separates the numbers as different elements of array where entered numbers are stored. -111 terminates input.
3. Every entered `int d` is stored as `char ch` such that:  `ch = (d + key)`. `char ch` is then stored to char array `msg[]`.
4. Char array `msg[]` is printed.

- **Example:**

message = "hello"

PIN = 123456

Key = (1+2+3+4+5+6) - [(1+2+3+4+5+6)/6] = 21 - (21/6) = 21 - 3.5 = ~ 18 (stored as 18, since key must be an int.)

ciphertext = 86 83 90 90 93 -8 33 -111

Comment: It's [instantly solvable from half a line of ciphertext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicity_distance#Unicity_distance_of_substitution_cipher), even without knowing that the method doesn't shuffle the alphabet. Is this a puzzle though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is trivially crackable. It says

> `Congratulations on decrypting this message ! ... I did not think it would be very secure anyways ;)`

It can easily be cracked by

> just taking the lowest number, and using a shift of whatever would make that a space (32). Here, the lowest number is 4, so the key is 28.
>
>
>   Or, if you're too lazy to do the math there, you can just try all possible shifts. There aren't many options that will keep everything in the printable ASCII range.

This is a substitution cipher, so it is also crackable with fairly well-known cryptanalysis techniques. Frequency analysis easily breaks any substitution cipher with more than a few words of text; sites like [Quipqiup](http://quipqiup.com) do this automatically.

The "PIN" here doesn't have anything to do with the actual algorithm. It has effectively no security: its only purpose is to generate the key, and many different PINs will map to the same key.

So, this is *less* secure than the Caesar cipher, because you can figure out the key directly from the data without having tried a decryption!

Comment: What if the user uses _  instead of space  ?

Comment: @JakeFry Then you just start at the key that that method gives you, and keep increasing  by 1 until you get it. The range you need to try will still be smaller than 25 (which is what a Caesar cipher would get you).

Comment: No, i dint get you... There are 0 spaces , only _ ...

Comment: for example, decrypt this 31 32 33 34 77 98 86 87 97 77 87 97 77 92 99 98 97 -8 85 -111

Comment: @JakeFry It's `1234_this_is_nuts`. I only had to try a few possible keys. It's very easy to do, even by hand. Since the "key" is just a single small number, all you have to do is try a few numbers until you get to the right one -- it takes *seconds* to figure out if you set it up in a spreadsheet. Start with the smallest number that gets them all into the range of printable ASCII, and just keep incrementing until you find the one that gives a message.

Comment: Brilliant. Deusovi, what , in you opinion, would be the **simplest** cryptographic algorithm which is also secure enough to use commercially ? ( asking out of interest , I'm only a hobbyist dev)

Comment: @JakeFry I'm no cryptographer -- I just know what's relevant to puzzle-solving. (Alternative snarky answer: The one-time pad.) But, from what I know, you *should not write your own cryptography methods for commercial purposes*. Use libraries given by your language. It is very easy to screw up cryptography.

Comment: Thanks Deusovi. I shall come back here with a much better improved cipher.

Comment: @JakeFry Questions about cryptography aren't really what this site is about -- this question already seems to not be very puzzle-y. I'm not sure whether more in-depth questions like this would be on-topic.

Comment: Deusovi, crack this one, can ya ? Its much more challenging : `40 77 77 60 6b 6e 29 69 73 19 6b 69 75 6d 2f 29 67 30 7c 73 75 6e 75 2c 70 20 74 26 74 68 6b 6c 70 67 66 27 66 28 69 5e 27 7a 68 63 6b 82 27 29 28 -6f`  (I promise, its valid, and has a valid algorithm behind it)